# BitmapImage from ByteArray/MemoryStream: Pixel format not supported

Tags: c#, bitmapimage, pixelformat

I am converting a BitmapImage from byte array, and it works fine, except with one specific .tif file. It gives an exception at EndInit():

> The bitmap pixel format is unsupported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F80)

The code used to read the byte array to BitmapImage is:

```
public BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] ImageData)       
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit(); //Exception here
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

What does this mean? The image opens just fine in windows, so it is not corrupted or anything. Is there a way to convert the image to supported pixel format, before the EndInit?

Comment: What format is it? Normally you can see it, for instance, in the explorer/properties.

Comment: What I can gather from the image properties: Item Type is TIF File, Compression is JPEG and Photometric interpretation is YCbCr